# C# Override Method at Runtime

Tags: c#, methods, runtime, overriding

I have two questions.

1) I found a little gem of code for [how to make a control scroll smoothly](http://brajesh.wordpress.com/2006/01/10/net-smooth-scrolling-panel/).

Great. But it overrides the WndProc method, so to use it, I had to tear out the FlowLayoutPanel I'd dropped on the form at design time, subclass FlowLayoutPanel, and then finally instantiate my new class and create all the properties manually and change all references to the control to be this.Controls["ControlName"]. (Or I guess I could make a class-level variable which is essentially what the control originally was, though how do they let you use intellisense on it when it's not declared anywhere?)

So now I'm just wondering if there was in fact a runtime way to do it.

Can I do something simple as this, where MainPanel is the name of the control:

```
MainPanel = (SmoothScrollingFlowLayoutPanel)MainPanel
```

It can't be that easy, can it? Even so, it's annoying because I still have to have the subclass (which may be a good design decision but I'd like the freedom to one-off it). So would it be possible to put the code into the parent of the FlowLayoutPanel something like this:

```
private Delegate void WndProcHandler(ref Message m);
private WndProcHandler w;

public void SomeCode() {
   w = MainPanel.WndProc; // get reference to existing wndproc method
   MainPanel.WndProc = WndProcSmoothScroll; //replace with new method
}

private void WndProcSmoothScroll(ref Message m) { // make smooth scrolling work
   if (
      (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
      && (((int)m.WParam & 0xFFFF) == 5)
   ) {
      m.WParam = (IntPtr)(((int)m.WParam & ~0xFFFF) | 4);
   }
   if (w != null) { w(); }
   base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
```

I realize this is probably pretty naive. I'm treating the WndProc method like it is an event, and it's not.

2) So then my second question is, if WndProc *was* an event instead of a method, how would I do the same thing—store a copy of the original list of handlers for an event, install my own event handler to run first, then call all the original event handlers?

**TASTY BITS**

In case anyone is interested I noticed an optimization possible in the smooth scrolling code:

```
//m.WParam = (IntPtr)(((int)m.WParam & ~0xFFFF) | 4);
m.WParam = (IntPtr)((int)m.WParam ^ 1);
```

Since we want to turn the last 16 bits from 5 to 4, we can just flip the last bit (XOR) rather than AND then OR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you want to do is override `WndProc` at runtime.  If so, all you need is a little Win32 magic.

Every control has a "handle" which identifies it so the operating system can send messages to it.  This handle is exposed through the `Handle` property on every control.  The underlying Win32 system actually allows you to listen to any control's `WndProc` as long as you have its handle.  This means that you don't have to inherit from a Winforms control to modify its Win32 behavior.  `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow` in .NET wraps this underlying functionality.

Here's an example of how you might accomplish this:

```
class SmoothScrollIntercept : System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow
{
    public SmoothScrollIntercept(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        // assign the handle and listen to this control's WndProc
        this.AssignHandle(hWnd);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // listen to WndProc here, do things

        if ((m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
            && (((int)m.WParam & 0xFFFF) == 5)) 
        {
            m.WParam = (IntPtr)(((int)m.WParam & ~0xFFFF) | 4);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    } 
}
```

Then in the code behind, attach the intercept to the control:

```
SmoothScrollIntercept intercept = new SmoothScrollIntercept(myControl.Handle);

// myControl is now using smooth scrolling, without inheriting from the control
```

Comment: Thank you Zach, but I've already accomplished making my windows scroll smoothly. I just hated how I had to rip the control out of the designer and do everything dynamically.

Comment: @Emtucifor:  No problem, I just wanted to let you know that you didn't have to inherit from `FlowLayoutPanel` to override its `WndProc`.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks. I confess I didn't read as carefully as I should have. This is useful! In fact, you're 100% right, it's the answer I was looking for. (smacks forehead)

Answer (score 2):

No, what you are asking for is impossible. You'll have to subclass as you did before.

Even if it were an event, you wouldn't be able to do what you're after. The public interface for an event only exposes `add` and `remove`; there is no way to obtain or assign the actual delegate(s) attached to the event.

<strike>However, looking at the problem from a *different* perspective, you may be able to make use of the [`IMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) interface in order to accomplish the end result you're looking for.</strike>

**Edit**

After looking at your code again, `IMessageFilter` won't work, as you cannot modify the message within `PreFilterMessage`; you can only examine or suppress it. Your best bet at this point is to override `WndProc` in the parent `Form` and try to make your manipulations there. It doesn't look like there's a generic solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I know a bit of javascript where you can do this with methods, so I was just curious.

Now it occurs to me, can I inherit both a FlowLayoutPanel AND a UserControl so that my new SmoothScrollingFlowLayoutPanel becomes an item I can drop on the form at design time?

Comment: @Emtucifor: No, none of the .NET languages allow for multiple inheritance. You can, however, inherit from `FlowLayoutPanel` and put your control in the toolbox. If the control is in your project, it should appear there automatically. If it's in another project, you'll have to right-click on the toolbox, click "Choose Items...", then browse to that .dll and add the control that way.

Comment: That was helpful. I knew that subclassed UserControls would show in the toolbox but somehow missed that subclassed regular controls would appear there, too. Thanks.